# How can I have separate profile in browsing, for Admin Accounts and Other Accounts and Guest Account?

Tags: google-chrome

How can I have separate profile in browsing, for Admin Accounts and Other Accounts and Guest Account?

I'm the Admin on my PC, but my sisters and nephews also using my PC.
In what way I ca install Chrome so that my browsing histories, bookmarks, extensions, add-ons, forms, saved passwords, etc., would be hidden from them, that they will have their own browsing histories, bookmarks, extensions, add-ons, forms, saved passwords, etc.?

Comment: You don’t do this in Chrome. You create a separate Windows account.

Comment: Yeah, so think I. You should create a new user account instead, but in Chrome you can just sign in using a different account, I think.

Comment: Do u mean, all infos/contents will not be shown on the other Accounts browsers, like bookmarks, extensions, histories, downloads list,etc.?

We will have separate infos/contents, even if I install browswers only once, using Admin Accounts? Did I get it right?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome allows multiple profiles, so that people don't mess with each-others accounts, but there is no way to hide browsing history from others, because nothing stops them from logging into your profile.
To implement profiles follow these steps:
Add a new user

Click the Chrome menu [image: Chrome menu] on the browser toolbar and select **Settings**.
    In the “Users” section, click **Add new user**.
    A confirmation dialog appears, choose a picture and enter a name for the new Chrome user.